# overriding actions for botium webdriverio connector

Tags: testing, chatbot

edit: change topic to overriding basic functons on botium-webdriverio-connector

---

How to trigger button click ?

from this link:
https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/wiki/Botium-Scripting

it says that you just need to put

```
#me
BUTTON btnTitle
```

but what actually happened is that it sends literal `BUTTON btnTitle` as text to the bot

[image: not clicking button]

for context, i implemented a custom WEBDRIVERIO_GETBOTMESSAGE and send back this

```
{
  "sender": "bot",
  "buttons": [
    {
      "text": "reply1"
    },
    {
      "text": "reply2"
    }
  ],
  "cards": [],
  "media": []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i decided to override the WEBDRIVERIO_SENDTOBOT function.
running on botium-cli 0.0.44, probably there are better solutions on newer versions.

---

edit: add more details, source code & implementation

in the end, i override these functions `WEBDRIVERIO_OPENBOT` `WEBDRIVERIO_SENDTOBOT`  `WEBDRIVERIO_GETBOTMESSAGE` and also add a custom asserter to assert gallery messages

botium.json

```
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "Production Test",
      "CONTAINERMODE": "webdriverio",
      "WEBDRIVERIO_OPTIONS": {  
        "desiredCapabilities": {
          "browserName": "chrome"      
        }
      },
      "WEBDRIVERIO_URL": "the bot url",
      "WEBDRIVERIO_OPENBOT": "./actions/open_test",
      "WEBDRIVERIO_IGNOREWELCOMEMESSAGES": 1,
      "WEBDRIVERIO_SENDTOBOT": "./actions/send",
      "WEBDRIVERIO_GETBOTMESSAGE": "./actions/parse_response",
      "WEBDRIVERIO_START_SELENIUM": true,
      "WEBDRIVERIO_START_SELENIUM_OPTS": {
        "drivers": {
          "chrome": {
            "version": "2.36"
          }
        }
      },
      "ASSERTERS": [
        {
          "ref": "GALLERY",
          "src": "./asserters/gallery",
          "global": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

./actions/open_test

```
module.exports = (container, browser) => {
    return browser
        .waitForVisible('#toggle-chat', 20000)
        .click('#toggle-chat') // click chat button
        .pause(2000)
        .waitForVisible('#get-started', 20000)
        .click('#get-started') // click get started, initiate the chat
        .pause(2000)
}
```

./actions/send

```
module.exports = (container, browser, msg) => {

    if (msg.messageText && msg.messageText !== '' && msg.messageText.indexOf('BUTTON') !== 0) { // send text message
        return browser
            .waitForEnabled('#text-input', 10000)
            .setValue('#text-input', msg.messageText)
            .keys('Enter')
    } else if (msg.messageText.indexOf('BUTTON') === 0) { // if message started with "BUTTON xxx", safe to assume the tester want to click button xxx
        let buttonTitle = msg.messageText.split(' ')[1]
        if (!buttonTitle) throw new Error('BUTTON invalid (1)')

        return browser.waitForEnabled(`[chatmessagebuttontitle="${ buttonTitle }"]`, 10000)
        .click(`[chatmessagebuttontitle="${ buttonTitle }"]`)
    } else { // unhandled, send arbitary message
        return browser
            .waitForEnabled('#text-input', 10000)
            .setValue('#text-input', 'unhandled')
            .keys('Enter')
    }

}
```

./actions/parse_response

```
module.exports = (container, browser, elementId) => {

    const botMsg = { sender: 'bot', buttons: [], cards: [], media: [] }

    /**
    *
    * ... parsing some html here to populate buttons, media and cards
    * ... can't put all the code for security reasons, sorry
    * ... here are example
    *
    * btw, elementId is NOT an html id attribute, so cannot query with "#" + elementId
    * cannot find documentation for webdriver elementId, but this page helps
    * http://v4.webdriver.io/api/protocol/elementIdElements.html
    *
    */

    browser.elementIdElements(elementId, '.bot-bubble')
    .then(elements => elements.value)
    .then(elements => 
        Promise.all(
            elements.map(element => 
                browser.elementIdText(element.ELEMENT).then(text => text.value)
            )
        ).then(messages => {
            // i only need the first message, also this function only called for each bot message bubble, so safe to assume there is only 1 message
            if (messages.length > 0) botMsg.messageText = messages[0] 

            // send the bot response back to botium
            container.BotSays(botMsg)
        })
    )

}
```

./asserter/gallery

```
/**
 * @typedef Card
 * @property {String} image
 * @property {String} title
 * @property {String} subtitle
 * @property {Array<String>} buttons
 * 
 * @typedef BotMesage
 * @property {Array<Card>} cards
 */

/**
 * @typedef GalleryAssertStepParam
 * @property {*} convo
 * @property {Array<String>} args
 * @property {BotMesage} botMsg
 */

module.exports = class GalleryAsserter {

    /**
     * this function is called whenever parse_response.js finishes
     * @param {GalleryAssertStepParam} param
     */
    assertConvoStep(param) {
        let args = param.args
        let botMsg = param.botMsg

        // args needs to be an array, simple check
        if (!args.concat) return Promise.reject(new Error('args for GALLERY is not an array'))
        if (args.length > botMsg.cards.length) return Promise.reject(new Error('number of gallery cards doesnt match. expecting ' + args.length +'. Got ' + botMsg.cards.length))

        // basic logic to check if the card that is passed from parse_response.js is equals to card that is written in test scripts 
        for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

            // ParseGalleryString is a function that convert arbitary string to a Card object
            // example of the arbitary string: "( title=some title, subtitle= some subtitle, image=image url, buttons=btn1, btn2, btn3 )"
            // will be converted to JSON { title: "some title", subtitle: "some subtitle", ... }
            let card = ParseGalleryString(args[i])
            let testcard = botMsg.cards[i]

            if (card.image !== testcard.image) return Promise.reject(new Error(`card[${i}] doesn't pass. expecting image to be ${ card.image }, got ${ testcard.image }`))
            if (card.title !== testcard.title) return Promise.reject(new Error(`card[${i}] doesn't pass. expecting title to be ${ card.title }, got ${ testcard.title }`))
            if (card.subtitle !== testcard.subtitle) return Promise.reject(new Error(`card[${i}] doesn't pass. expecting subtitle to be ${ card.subtitle }, got ${ testcard.subtitle }`))

            if (card.buttons.length !== testcard.buttons.length) return Promise.reject(new Error(`card[${i}] doesn't pass. expecting ${ card.buttons.length }(${card.buttons.join(', ')}) buttons, got ${ testcard.buttons.length }(${testcard.buttons.join(', ')})`))
            if (card.buttons.join('_') !== testcard.buttons.join('_')) return Promise.reject(new Error(`card[${i}] doesn't pass. expecting buttons to be ${ card.buttons.join(', ') }, got ${ testcard.buttons.join(', ') }`))
        }

        return Promise.resolve()
    }

}
```

then to use the custom asserter
testgallery.convo.txt

```
Test Gallery

#me
show me some cat breeds

#bot
here are some cat breeds

#bot
GALLERY (image=http://cat.pic/1.png, title=Alaskan Malmute, subtitle=This is actually not a cat, buttons=Pet, Give Food, Info) | (image=http://cat.pic/2.png, title=Cobra Kai, subtitle=This is actually a movie, buttons=Watch, Like, Dislike)
```

this setup works for botium-cli version 0.0.44
tried to update to botium 0.0.45 but got some error on selenium driver

Comment: just for the records, it would be cool if you extended this post with the actual code of what you did

Comment: the gallery asserter looks nice and can be of use for other users as well. would you mind if i add it to botium core ? or if you want to get the credits, you might maje a pull request with your code as well ...

Comment: sure, you can use it. pull request might takes time, so please just go ahead

Answer (score 0):

Triggering button clicks is part of [Botium Core 1.4.8](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/releases/tag/1.4.8). For button clicks the result of WEBDRIVERIO_GETBOTMESSAGE is not considered, Botium just looks for button titles (source code with default selenium selector is [here](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-webdriverio/blob/master/index.js#L81).

The described behaviour, that the literal text is sent to the bot, is most likely due to an older version of Botium Core. Please check the version you are using. If you are using version 1.4.8, please [enable logging](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/wiki/Troubleshooting) and extend your question with the log output.

Comment: hi, sorry if this sound stupid, but how do i know which botium core version im using right now ? "botium-cli --version" returns "0.0.44" but i doubt its the botium-core version

Comment: Please get the latest Botium CLI 0.0.45 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/botium-cli)

Comment: is there any step that i need to take after updating ? got this error after update: "Error: Failed to start selenium: Error: Missing /usr/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/chromedriver/2.36-x64-chromedriver". i installed botium-cli using "sudo sudo npm install -g botium-cli@0.0.45 --unsafe-perm"

Comment: or, how can i override the button click behaviour ?. edit: nvm, i think can use WEBDRIVERIO_SENDTOBOT to customize the behaviour, will get back if it succeeds, thanks.

Comment: When using the integrated Selenium server, you have to first install the drivers you need. It is actually complaining that chromedriver is not available. Installing it over botium-cli is currently not possible (task is in our backlog), so you should start your selenium server outside of Botium for now. (see [here](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-webdriverio#start-the-integreated-selenium-server)

Comment: ya, i ran the selenium server separately, using that repo actually, 'npm run selenium', 0.0.45 didn't work with that error, revert back to 0.0.44 then work again.