# Botium Box Community Edition for testing chatbots

Tags: chatbot, ibm-watson, web-api-testing

I'm using Botium Box Community Edition for testing chatbots. I'm not able to get intent details, intent confidence, and entity in the corresponding Test set report.  Also, can we test API and other back-end details of our chatbot through Botium Box? Is there is any more documentation available for Botium Box?

Answer (score 1):

Test Reporting and API backend assertions are part of Botium Box paid plans (http://www.botium.at/pricing.html).
Botium is very developer friendly though, so with some Javascript experience - for example, there is a user who already developed his own asserter: [overriding actions for botium webdriverio connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54645876/overriding-actions-for-botium-webdriverio-connector/54685047#comment96191528_54685047)